# What has been the growth rate of tangle confirmation rate until today?

Tags: transaction, tangle, iota-network, confirmation

I am curious to understand how the tangle has improved in terms of confirmation rate since its inception. Are there any statistics which show this? A positive growth is definitely a good sign. And if the differential of this growth rate is also positive its an even better sign.

Comment: @AustinPowers, thanks for pointing to the data. I plotted the data which had transactions since May 16th, since the duration of data is not quite enough I couldn't see any trend. Hopefully your students results by the end of summer will have some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global confirmation rate (ctps) is unfortunately not a good indicator of the healthiness of the tangle. (and I say "unfortunately" because many commentators believe it is).

Why global ctps isn't a good indicator ?

IOTA is a permissionless and feeless network, so it is easy for anyone to setup a node using an unfair tip-selection algorithm, flooding the network with invalid transactions and impacting the ctps negatively. That's exactly what we see today with the "side-tangle".

A good indicator would be the ctps of transactions attached to the tangle using a fair tip-selection algorithm. AFAIK, today it's impossible to compute this kind of indicator accurately (because when looking at a transaction, it's impossible to say (with 100% certainty) what kind of tip-selection algorithm was used to attach it).

You can find some historical data [here](http://traviota.iotalt.com/download) but it contains data only since  Friday, May 18, 2018 4:37:00 PM GMT and keep track of **value transaction only**.

Comment: *today it's impossible to compute this kind of indicator accurately* - it can be done experimentally. In fact, I have a student working on this - he's tracking the confirmation rate of transactions created by him through time. Results hopefully coming at the end of summer.